# GWT with a Content Management System

Tags: java, gwt, content-management-system, seo, gwt-rpc

I have GWT page with rich functionality. I wanted to use this module in different web sites as a widget. But due to limited flexibility of this module I can't change design easily, nor embed this module into different SEO(search engine optimized) pages.

If there any CMS or methodology to ease work with GWT?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GaSP: http://code.google.com/p/gasp-web-engine/

It's a CMS that I wrote based on GWT/SQL/PHP. It's pretty flexible. Let me know if you are willing to test it out.

It runs my site: http://www.stevenjaycohen.com

Steven

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've looked at your website it is not crawlable for search engines and it is pure GWT. The idea was to use GWT generated .js inside other pages as a gadget.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already ruled out embedding the module in different websites, but have you checked out [GWT Exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/)

> The project is a GWT module which
>   contains a generator capable of taking
>   GWT classes and exporting them as
>   ordinary Javascript APIs callable from
>   hand-written Javascript without JSNI,
>   and suitable for use in mashups.

It might allow you to expose your existing module, without modification, using pure JS. It would likely simplify embedding your module in other sites

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Yes I checked out GWT Exporter and it is not what I need. It would contradict to the original idea of using GWT "avoid writing any kind of JS code by hand". What I want is something that can be used as CMS and host GWT as well. Now I'm playing with OpenSocial container such as apache-shinding.