# Using GWT with CMS (like Vosao)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, content-management-system, vosao

I have a working website built completely with GWT. I want to test it to be used in a CMS; since using a CMS is likely to be the way for easier maintainance in the future instead of having to rewrite code so much.

Here's the reason why I use GWT:

- Don't want to write JS code and manipuate pages using JS.
- Most importantly I want to reuse my dynamic widgets, like the Flextable I use to populate the products page, instead of dealing with CSS and template (and stuff like that)

Bottleneck with this is that is quite not easy to use with a CMS (like Vosao)

What is the proper strategy on using GWT with a CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your site begin to **grow in size and complexity**.

Page counts number in the hundreds, rather than the **few**.

The CMS begins to become more of an application **platform to achieve    specific communications and informational objectives.**

See  this also for more discussions :[GWT with a Content Management System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952220/gwt-with-a-content-management-system)